# SyntaxError when trying to change files (JSON)

Tags: json

This code has suddenly stopped working in Visio Studio Code. it is suppose to change the JSON file text I got this code from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWdyi5EGxq4. here's the code below. Help would be appreciated thanks.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { json } = require("stream/consumers");
const args = process.argv.slice(2);
const inputFolder = args[0];
const dir = `${__dirname}/${inputFolder}/`;
const inputFiles = fs.readdirSync(dir).sort();

inputFiles.forEach((file) => {
    let id = file.split(".").shift();
    let data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${dir}/${file}`));

    data.name = `ipfwork/${id}`;
    
   fs.writeFileSync(`${dir}/${file}`, JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
   console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Mind to tell us *what* error you get?

Comment: you have to check a web browser console to find the error

Comment: @Serge I doubt something containing `require(fs)` or `fs.writeFileSync` will actually be run in a browser ...

Comment: @derpirscher JavaScript is working  only in a browser.  And what about  console.log(data) ?

Comment: The code per se looks fine. Maybe there is a syntax error in one of the JSON files you are reading. That will throw an exception on `JSON.parse` ...

Comment: @Serge *"javascript is working only in a browser"*? Seriously? Are you telling me, you never heard of [node.js](https://nodejs.org) or [deno](https://deno.land/)?